# Basic CSS +grid: How do I keep one dynamic grid cell from blowing out my entire grid container?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I know this is a common question, but I haven't seen anyone answer it without switching away from grid or hardcoding pixel sizes (which seems like bad practice), so wanted to see if it's possible:

I am trying to create a simple grid with two cells. I want the top cell to dynamically size to what's left of the parent grid container. I want the bottom cell to remain fixed at the bottom of the parent grid container.

The top container will contain all the messages to read in a chat app.
The bottom container will contain a compose bar to write and send a message.

To feel natural, the top container (message list) should scroll when it overflows.
The bottom container (compose bar) should remain fixed at the bottom of the screen.

**The problem with my code** is that the top container always expands to the full length of the stacked messages when the list is long enough to overflow the container. (I am mapping an array of messages to divs within `chat-message-list`). It's so aggressive, it not only pushed the bottom cell below the fold, it pushed elements outside the grid down as well.

```css
#chat {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr 64px / 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* This does nothing */
}

#chat-read {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#chat-compose {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
}

#chat-message-list {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat">
  <div id="chat-read">
    <div id="chat-message-list">
      ... /* Variable amount of divs containing a chat message each */
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="chat-compose">
    ... /* Fixed-height compose bar */
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the maximum height of the `.chat-message-list` to come from? The constraints of an ancestor, a hard-coded maximum..? Also, from [Una Kravets](https://una.im/) and [Adam Argyle](https://nerdy.dev/), "*[why isn't percentage working?](https://youtu.be/yciaKrzWmi4?si=oIL-R2rxllZ4Or8m&t=20)*"

Comment: This is essentially the crux of my question--I want the max height to be the visible portion of the screen. It should change dynamically as the window is resized. Does 100% not specify that? I don't want to hardcode a pixel value arbitrarily.

Comment: @DavidThomas In reality, this grid is nested inside another 3-cell grid which had a 50px top nav bar and a 50px bottom nav bar. I gave this middle cell a hardcoded value of 100vh - 100px. This feels like a janky solution, but nothing else seemed to keep it from kicking the bottom nav bar off the screen. Is there a better way?

Comment: There may well be a better way, but may I suggest that you think about what you're trying to do, think about the information you might need to answer the question (hypothetically, obviously), read the guidance on (relevant) [mcve] code, and [edit] your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a maximum height for, ideally, the `body` or the parent of your chat div for the 100% height to take effect.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  max-height: 100vh;
}

#chat {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr 64px / 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#chat-read {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#chat-compose {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
  background: lightblue;
}

#chat-message-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat">
  <div id="chat-read">
    <div id="chat-message-list">
      <div>Chat 1</div>
      <div>Chat 2</div>
      <div>Chat 3</div>
      <div>Chat 4</div>
      <div>Chat 5</div>
      <div>Chat 6</div>
      <div>Chat 7</div>
      <div>Chat 8</div>
      <div>Chat 9</div>
      <div>Chat 10</div>
      <div>Chat 11</div>
      <div>Chat 12</div>
      <div>Chat 13</div>
      <div>Chat 14</div>
      <div>Chat 15</div>
      <div>Chat 16</div>
      <div>Chat 17</div>
      <div>Chat 18</div>
      <div>Chat 19</div>
      <div>Chat 20</div>
      <div>Chat 21</div>
      <div>Chat 22</div>
      <div>Chat 23</div>
      <div>Chat 24</div>
      <div>Chat 25</div>
      <div>Chat 26</div>
      <div>Chat 27</div>
      <div>Chat 28</div>
      <div>Chat 29</div>
      <div>Chat 30</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="chat-compose">
    ... /* Fixed-height compose bar */
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below code:

```css
*{margin: 0;padding: 0;box-sizing: border-box;}
p{margin-bottom: 10px;}
#chat {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr 100px / 100%;
  height: 100%; /* This does nothing */
}

#chat-read {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: azure;
}

#chat-compose {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  padding: 20px;
}

#chat-message-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat">
        <div id="chat-read">
          <div id="chat-message-list">
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="chat-compose">
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
            <p>Hi</p>
            <p>Hello,</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```